# Django model custom save with ManyToManyField problem

Tags: django, model, save, manytomanyfield

I know this question has been posted multiple times but I still couldn't find a definite answer to this problem. So, here I go:

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    program = models.ForeignKey(Program)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name='invoices')
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(Participant, related_name='participants_set')
    subtotal = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default='0.00', blank=True, null=False)
    pst = models.DecimalField("PST", max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default='0.00', blank=True, null=False)
    gst = models.DecimalField("GST", max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default='0.00', blank=True, null=False)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default='0.00', blank=True, null=False)

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        super(Invoice, self).save(**kwargs)
        items = self.participants.count()
        subtotal = Decimal(self.program.fee) * items
        pst = self.program.is_pst and Decimal(PST)*subtotal or Decimal('0.00')
        gst = self.program.is_gst and Decimal(GST)*subtotal or Decimal('0.00')
        total = (subtotal + pst) + gst
        self.subtotal = subtotal
        self.pst = pst
        self.gst = gst
        self.total = total
        super(Invoice, self).save(**kwargs)
```

Everything works fine except self.participants.count() doesn't work. Any idea what could be the problem. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What version of Django? Your call to self.participants.count() should work.

Comment: Does the count method raise an exception, or does it give the wrong value?

Answer (score 5):

```
self.participants.all().count()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overriding the save method, I'd recommend using the [pre-save signal](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save). Besides making your code a bit cleaner, it helps avoid strange issues like these :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening is because you are trying a participants count during a save, the query may not be finding everything.  If you're depending on this number at database creation time, I don't think the many-to-many table will be synced up correctly because the `Invoice` doesn't have an ID assigned yet.

Conversely, the other participants may not be saved to the database.  Either way, depending on this number during a save won't work, regardless of using signals.  I would recommend having a separate method that does this computation.  It's cleaner, it improves save performance, and you can call it without saving.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea to separate the participants altogether and just record the quantity (number of participants). That way the Invoice model would be more generic.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I had a model that supported del.icio.us style tags. The save function would parse a list of the tags (e.g. "python django web") and convert them into individual tag object instances by calling a helper function *update_tags()* (see below for a simplified example). However, the ManyToManyField would not reflect the changes when I edited the object within the admin interface.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    tag_string = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True) #del.icio.us style tags, like: django python software
    tags =  models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
        super(Article, self).save(force_insert, force_update)

        self.update_tags() #The result of this function didn't seem to be saved in the ManyToManyField
```

It turns out that the admin interface was overriding the changes to the ManyToManyField. The solution was simply to remove the ManyToManyField from the admin.ModelAdmin:

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ['tags']
```